# Encoding write db issue to SQL after 1024 row

Tags: r, odbc, freetds, r-dbi

I'm trying to write table to MS SQL Server from R using DBI with Cyrillic words.
All looking good but when I write more then 1024 rows I have issue with encoding.
I'm try next drivers :

- Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
- ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
- FreeTDS Driver v0.91
- RStudio Professional Drivers

  But result was the same:
  [image]

**UPDATE**:
example
file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/t6sjcq3f1mdbxcz/q3.csv?dl=0

```
con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                 driver = "Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server",
                 server = "amazonaws.com,1433",
                 database = "",
                 uid = "",
                 pwd = "")

con%>%dbWriteTable("to_forecast",q3,overwrite=T,field.types=list(calendarid="float",ActivityID="float",ActioName="nvarchar(255)",TypePromoID="float",
                                                     Micro_Name="nvarchar(255)",Mechanics="float",MechanicType_Name="nvarchar(255)",
                                                     LagerType_Name="nvarchar(255)",id="float",LagerId="float",FullName="nvarchar(255)",
                                                     ShortName="nvarchar(255)",PriceBeforeAction="float",PriceAction="float",
                                                     DiscountPercent="float",PriceBeforeAction.1="float",macroid="float",minFCriDate="nvarchar(255)",
                                                     Calc="float",CalcOK="float",SumFKolvo="float",DateBegin="nvarchar(255)",DateFinish="nvarchar(255)",
                   LastEKT="float",ID_last_level="float",Name_last_level="nvarchar(255)",id0="float",Level0="float",macro0="nvarchar(255)",id1="float",
                   Level1="float",macro1="nvarchar(255)",id2="float",Level2="float",macro2="nvarchar(255)",id3="float",Level3="float",
                   macro3="nvarchar(255)",id4="float",Level4="float",macro4="nvarchar(255)",id5="float",Level5="float",macro5="nvarchar(255)",
                   id6="float",Level6="float"))
```

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @nak5120 done. csv looking with bad encoding, but when open on PC it's ok